# Run Helm Command within a pod

Tags: openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run helm command within a pod. Here is my yaml

I did run a oc command

oc create -f mycron.yaml

Here is my mycron.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronbox
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cronbox
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the openshift cluster; helm version
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

When the schedule pick up, and when the commands run  i see the below result

helm: command not found

I am expecting the helm version to be printed which i can see in the logs of the pod

Comment: That command runs inside of a container. The `busybox` image used for that container is not going to contain the `helm` command. Where are you expecting the `helm` program to be picked up from?

Comment: That's my problem i think. How can i make my pod at run time get the helm program?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you'll have to start using a different image such as `alpine/helm:2.9.0`, which contains the helm cli tools.

Comment: thanks @RickRackow,now i am trying to delete temporary pods like below and it results in error
`apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronbox
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cronbox
            image: alpine/helm:2.9.1
            args:
            - delete
            - --purge
            - $(helm ls -a -q 'tempods*')
          restartPolicy: OnFailure`
Error:pods is forbidden:User"system:serviceaccount:"cannot list pods in the namespace...no RBAC policy match

Comment: You'll need to have a service account for helm to use tiller with as well as an actual tiller service account
https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md